# How to use multiple targets inside React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm building an application like Uber in React Native

my purpose is to have 2 targets inside the main app , one for driver and the other for the client

this technique is useful to share the common codes between 2 targets without writing them twice for each target

this technique is already exist in IOS development inside (XCode) and Android Development  inside (Android Studio)

I searched for tutorials about using this technique with React Native , but looks something not popular with RN

while searching I reached to [this link](https://gist.github.com/jacks205/45b2721bf2a2b912b1c130aef2572820) , but seems not what I'm looking for

Comment: The react-natove-rename would be another option:` npx react-native-rename <newName> -b <bundleIdentifier>`